# Gradient in xml for a linear layout

Tags: android, view, gradient

How to set gradient in xml for a linear layout. I want to draw borders with round cornered edges for the view in a layout. Post some example if any one has tried.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define your xml the following way and place it in your *drawable* folder under the *res* directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="6dp" android:color="#FFCCCCCC"/>
    <padding android:left="5dp" android:top="5dp" android:right="5dp"
        android:bottom="5dp" />
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="#FFCCCCCC"
        android:centerColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:endColor="#FFCCCCCC"
        android:type="linear" />
</shape>
```

Then for your view you can set the gradient as:

```
yourView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nameofxml);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is code:

Create one roundedborder.xml file in res/drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
 <corners android:radius="6dp" /> 
<padding android:left="15dp" android:top="15dp"
    android:right="15dp" android:bottom="15dp" />
<stroke android:color="#10527c" android:width="2dp" />
<gradient
android:angle="270"
android:startColor="#FFCCCCCC"
android:centerColor="#FFFFFFFF"
android:endColor="#FFCCCCCC"
android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

Then Apply background resource to a layout in activity.

```
 tempLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.roundedborder);
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of view are you trying to create? For something like ListView, I suggest you use the below implementation and just make your changes to get the desired effects.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >

<gradient
    android:centerColor="#E6E6E6"
    android:endColor="#CCCCCC"
    android:startColor="#FFFFFF" 
    android:angle="270"/>
<!--
    <gradient
    android:startColor="#FF7500"
    android:centerColor="#FFCC00"
    android:endColor="#FF7500"
    android:angle="270"/>
-->

<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#A0000000" />

<padding
    android:bottom="8dp"
    android:left="5dp"
    android:right="5dp"
    android:top="8dp" />

<corners android:radius="5dp" />

</shape>
```